# Erlang ordered_set store terms reversely

Tags: erlang, ets

I just want to use ordered_set type of ets.

But the term I put is store in Erlang term sort, Like 1, 2, 3, 4...

How to store Erlang term in reversely order, like 4, 3, 2, 1

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible. `ordered_set` works with standard Erlang term order and has no way to override it. But you can use `ets:last` and `ets:prev` to iterate from the last to the first stored term.